# What does build automatically do for a maven project in eclipse?

Tags: maven-3, m2e

We recently converted to maven, I'm really new to it. I've imported the project into eclipse, the "build automatically" by default is on, and I have no idea what it does. Is there a way for me to see the logging message, to configure it so I can make it not to, say, use the default goal, but a different goal every time? BTW, currently, building in CLI is fine, but the resource filtering is not working in eclipse with "build automatically" turned on.
Thanks in advance!

David

Comment: Are you using m2e, or m2eclipse? It would help to tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a maven plugin will be executed in an *incremental eclipse build* depends on the "lifecycle mapping" configuration.

You will find (detailed) information about this topic on the "[M2E plugin execution not covered](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)" site.

A quote from this site:

> We call these instructions "project build lifecycle
>   mapping" or simply "lifecycle mapping" because they define how m2e
>   maps information from project pom.xml file to Eclipse workspace
>   project configuration and behaviour during Eclipse workspace build.

There are several possibilities how the lifecycle mapping can be configured (in the pom, in m2e extensions, since m2e 1.1 (SNAPSHOT) in metadata provided by the plugin).

You should have a look at this site and hopefully you will be able to setup a configuration/installation that fits your needs.

Comment: Even if I didn't get a direct answer, but I'm pointed to right direction.